# Can a quantum computer tell whether a program is Turing complete?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, complexity-theory

I am very new to quantum computing and would like to know if a quantum computer can decide whether a given program is Turing complete.

Comment: A quantum computer can be simulated by a classical computer, for example by keeping track of the wave function. It is also in general undecidable to determine whether a given machine is Turing complete, with a classical computer. So the answer to your question is “no”. But it’s still a reasonable question to ask.

Comment: It is correct that a quantum computer cannot solve the halting problem. However, what is true is that the "halting problem has an interactive proof involving quantum entangled provers". This is because MIP*=RE https://quantumfrontiers.com/2020/03/01/the-shape-of-mip-re/. Though the quantum computers required for such a task are likely impossible to construct.

Comment: I wondered about this too.  The OP’s question was specifically about showing Turing-completeness and not strictly about the halting problem. Presumably, from Rice’s theorem, MIP* also is powerful enough to decide whether a given Turing machine is complete, in polynomial time..

Comment: @Condo Thanks for the link! Fascinating read! It is perhaps relevant to note that the computers involved in $MIP^*$ are not quantum computers in the usual sense of the word. The verifier is a classical computer and the provers are *magical* quantum computers (in the sense that there are no bounds on their computational capabilities) that share arbitrary amount of entanglement, but cannot communicate with each other. As with non-deterministic Turing machines, I don't think anyone actually hopes to ever build one. Instead, their study sheds some light on the gap between search and verification.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to describe a program as "Turing complete". Turing completeness is a property of a computer or programming language or execution environment, not a property of a specific program

Comment: @Laith Striegher are you wondering whether a quantum computer can *solve* the halting problem, i.e. find an input $f$ for which a Turing machine $M$ halts, or whether it can *verify* if given a Turing machine $M$ halts on a specific input $f_0$? These are importantly different questions, however, realistically the answer is no for both.

Comment: @user18835 I read the OP's question broadly to ask whether any given Turing machine $M = \langle Q, \Gamma, b, \Sigma, \delta, q_0, F \rangle$ is Turing-complete.  This is a well-defined problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Classical and quantum computers are equivalent as far as questions of [computability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computability_theory) are concerned. The difference between them lies "merely" in the [resource use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory).

The equivalence follows from the fact that a quantum computer can simulate a classical computer and a classical computer can simulate a quantum computer. The former can be achieved with little overhead by performing reversible variant of the classical computation in the computational basis. The latter can be done for example using [Feynman's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%27s_algorithm) at the cost of exponential time overhead.

Consequently, quantum computers will not solve the [Halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), answer questions about [Turing completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) or decide other [non-trivial semantic properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) of computer programs.